# I'm trying to link my clickhouse cloud database to grafana on my remote device for visualization but unable to achieve so

Tags: grafana, linker-errors, clickhouse

I'm trying to link my **clickhouse cloud** database to **grafana on my remote device** for visualization.

I'm getting an error where it either shows:

- **connection timed out**
- or **plugin health check failed**

For tcp i entered the connection string value that we receive on clickhouse - e.g. `ln5xtq1kbr.asia-southeast1.gcp.clickhouse.cloud`

[image]

[image]

I am supposed to be getting a successfully linked message but im unable to achieve so.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud uses SSL and port 9440. Have a look here for details. https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/integrations/grafana#1-gather-your-connection-details

Comment: I did try that as well still recieving the same error of 'plugin health check failed'